# How can I upload photos from Android's mobile gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery, image-uploading

I want to upload photos from Android's mobile gallery from my app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `MediaStore` to be able to get pictures from the gallery:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

Edit:You can get the image with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

And you get the bitmap with this in your `onActivityResult` :

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity()
                    .getContentResolver(), data.getData());
```

Comment: i do not want to get image from gallery  i want to share it from phone gallery

Comment: you can also get the uri with the method, and so you could share the picture and give the uri as parameters to your sharing method... I think...